# Single or double quotes in PHP?

Tags: php, xss, string

In general which is safer to use, with regards to XSS evasion in particular?

```
echo '<input name="'.$input_name.'">';
echo "<input name='$input_name'>";
```

I'm guessing single quotes, but wondering why & hoping to find recommended reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't make a difference if used correctly.

The first version is standard though. Single quotes are less often used around HTML attribute values, so you need to be a bit more careful when using various functions meant to protect against XSS, as they may not necessarily take this case into consideration.

`htmlspecialchars` for example does not encode `'` by default, you need to specifically set `ENT_QUOTES`. Any custom function your project or framework may use may have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you use `"` in PHP you don't need to use `'` in HTML. I'd recommend

```
echo "<input name=\"$input_name\">";
```

or even

```
echo "<input name=\"".$input_name."\">";
```